# Votes also got migrated

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, migration

It seems that the votes also got transfered for [this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/7105/combinator-logic-and-unification) when it got migrated to here from SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct, votes are migrated with questions, and have always been.

Comment: Thanks Jeff for the answer. I didn't notice that votes also get migrated.

Comment: ps: It seems a little bit strange that users get reputation on a site based on the votes on another one. It changes the meaning of the total voted a migrated question has, I checked the votes because I was expecting a higher quality from a question that had 10 votes in less than a day. Between the 50 newest questions on cstheory all except one have less than 10 total votes.

Comment: More precisely, the [vote count is reset to 0 if negative](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6615/reset-negative-vote-counts-on-migrated-questions). But I think it [should be reset to 0 always](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87031/reset-votes-on-migrated-questions).